# Pyhive Presto insert select * from not running

Tags: python, presto, pyhive

I can us PYHIVE to connect to PRESTO and select data back just fine.  I am trying to use PYHIVE to run "insert into x select from y" on presto and it is not running.  I am sure I am missing something simple.

```
from pyhive import presto
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import pandas as pd

req_kw = {'auth': HTTPBasicAuth(user, pw),'verify':False}

conn = presto.connect(host=ht,port=prt,protocol='https',catalog='hive',username=user,requests_kwargs=req_kw)

cursor  = conn.cursor()

query='select count(1) from dim.date_dim '
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.fetchall())

query='insert into flowersc.date_dim select * from dim.date_dim'
cursor.execute(query)

query='select count(1) from flowersc.date_dim '
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

no errors occur

but the results show no data loaded

[(16624,)]
[(0,)]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there any data in the `flowersc.date_dim` location?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check (fetch) result in

```
query='insert into flowersc.date_dim select * from dim.date_dim'
cursor.execute(query).next() # added .next()
```

This is needed due to a change in Presto in May 2018 (https://github.com/prestosql/presto/commit/568449b8d058ed8281cc5277bb53902fd044cad7). But it's also a good practise to verify query results, i.e. check that your `INSERT` statement succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it is not failing with an error.

Comment: from pyhive import presto
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import pandas as pd
req_kw = {'auth': HTTPBasicAuth(user, pw),'verify':False}
conn = presto.connect(host=ht,port=prt,protocol='https',catalog='hive',username=user,requests_kwargs=req_kw)
cursor  = conn.cursor()
query='select count(1) from dim.date_dim '
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.fetchall())

query='insert into flowersc.date_dim select * from dim.date_dim'
cursor.execute(query).fetchall()

query='select count(1) from flowersc.date_dim '
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.fetchall())

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-233ce873a1e3> in <module>
     11 
     12 query='insert into flowersc.date_dim select * from dim.date_dim'
---> 13 cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
     14 
     15 query='select count(1) from flowersc.date_dim '

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Comment: I figured it out.  I used the next() method.